# ASP.Net and NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, namevaluecollection

I have the following method:

```
public object[] GetEventsByUser(DateTime start, DateTime end, string fullUrl)
```

The value of the fullUrl is:

http://localhost:50435/page/view.aspx?si=00&us=admin&ut=smt&

When I do:

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fullUrl);
```

I get:

{http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50435%2fpage%2fview.aspx%3fsi=00&us=admin&ut=smt&}

But I need to obtain the parameters in the QueryString of this page, and with this value, I cannot obtain the "si" value, because the question mark, that starts the querystring is encoded.
So I thought: "humm... I should try to do the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()"

However the method HtmlEncode returns void: However the second parameter of this method sends the value to a TextWriter. But it isn't the NameValueCollection.

Maybe the solution is simple... but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim it down to just the querystring before parsing, like this:

```
if (fullUrl.Contains("?")) {
  fullUrl = fullUrl.Substring(fullUrl.IndexOf("?") + 1);
}
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fullUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var si = Request["si"];
var user = Request["us"];
//etc.
```

Comment: You mean `Request.QueryString["si"]`.

Comment: I meant: Request["xy"], I changed this.